# How to not repeat arguments to formatted log4j2

Tags: log4j2

Presently I have the following:

```
String leaper = "frog";
logger.error("The {} jumped over the moon-{} then over the sun-{}", leaper, 
leaper,  leaper);
```

How can I write the leaper variable just once on the logger.error statement?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the different [kinds of log4j2 messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html) you'll see there is one called `StringFormattedMessage` which will allow you to do what you want. Here is an example:

```
log.info(new StringFormattedMessage("The %1$s jumped over the moon-%1$s then over the sun-%1$s", leaper));
```

Comment: Thanks you.
I used slightly different "String.format" instead of the "new StringFormattedMessage". but with the "%1$s", which was the piece I did not know.